# Imitating specific USB device

Tags: linux, windows, usb

I recently got hands on an workout device which has a USB to PC interface and logs workouts on a lousy Windows Application. My intention is to read out the USB and build a custom application for presenting that data.

When connected to a linux machine the device registers in `/dev/ttyUSB0`, can be seen with `lsusb` and `stty` reports the baudrate among other information. I fire up minicom with the stty settings and as soon as the workout is initiated the device sends a series of 41 bytes

I assume that those bytes represent an announcement to the the PC interface.

What I would like to do is to imitate the workout device and send those 41 bytes to the PC interface myself in order to see what the PC side does upon initiation. Is there a way to imitate the device so that the PC software will recognize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the device is `/dev/ttyUSB0` it is very likel implementing a virtual COM port, this is USB Communication Device class CDC (ACM).

the operating system knows what driver / kernel module it has to load because when you plug in the device in USB protocol descriptors are exchanged ( the device sends its device descriptor to the host, according to this the host loads the driver / kernel module ), you can see this information with `lsusb -v`. Specifically the device sends the following descriptors to the host : *device descriptor, configuration descriptor, interface descriptor, endpoint descriptor* : http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

for imitating a device you have to write a firmware on a MCU with exaclty these descriptors and additionally with identic VID ( vendor id ) and PID ( product id )

the 41 bytes you receive flow over the virtual COM port and so in RS-232 protocol ( you are able to receive them with minicom ) and so they are above USB level, however they are part of the payload in USB packets. if you have a proprietary driver in windows of your device in windows these 41 bytes are very likely addressed to the driver ( whichs source code you very likely do not have ...). this is very common there are multimeters with RS-232 interface and one has to send a  `D = 44 (hex) = 01000100 (bin)`  to receive any **d**ata

so you can try to sniff the virtual COM port ( RS-232 protocol ) directly using a **RS-232 sniffer**, i.e. https://www.eltima.com/rs232-sniffer.html

alternatively you can try is to sniff the underlying USB traffic with `wireshark` ( or `usbmon` in linux ) and extract the payload from the USB packets to record the communication between the windows driver and ther device

https://ask.wireshark.org/question/36/how-to-capture-usb-packets-please/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfkC7kmIMt8 ( USB in Wireshark )

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt

( https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/usb/URB.html )

Comment: That was some great info! The rs232-sniffer seems to do the job pretty much. I can see the function calls and the data moving up/down the virtual port. 
What I am wondering about is if I need all this when in Linux. Since the device pops up in Linux and data comes out of the Virtual port then I suppose I do not need the "driver" part and I can jump straight to the serial communication. Is that right?